# CSS not linking to HTML in IE 7 and IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'm creating a responsive website using several stlyesheets. Everything works fine in IE 9, Firefox and Safari, but the when I view the site in IE 8 or below, the styles disappear.

You can view the site at http://stevepolitodesign.comlu.com/ (I am hosting it for free for debugging purposes, so it may be down periodically)

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Steve Polito Design</title>

<!-- CSS -->
<link href="css/wide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1501px)" />
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 801px) and (max-width: 1500px)" />
<link href="css/medium.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px)" />
<link href="css/narrow.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 400px)" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="css/iphone.css"/>
<link href="css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen"/>


<!-- @font-face -->
<link href="fonts/@font-face.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>


</head>
```

Comment: ONE COMMENT: AMAZING WEBSITE!

Comment: Thanks! Trying to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The media attribute is part of CSS3 and is therefore not supported by IE 6/7/8.  See this article, http://nicolasgallagher.com/mobile-first-css-sass-and-ie/, for more information about it.

The quick solution is to add some lines that link to css files that are hidden to all but IE6-8.

```
<!--[if (gt IE 8) | (IEMobile)]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```